Get a "clang: error: no such file or directory" when building my Python package
I'm trying to install a package that I'm maintaining (pygtftk). I'm using the latest version and would like to go on with the development that I let few months ago (to prepare python 3.10 and 3.11 version). but I'm not able anymore to install it due to a weird clang/gcc error  (I tried both under Unix and OSX). I'm using Python 3.9.15 under Unix.
When running:
   git clone git@github.com:dputhier/pygtftk.git
   cd pygtftk
   python setup.py install --user

It complains about not finding the 'exclude.cpp' in current directory.
  gcc -pthread -B ...
  gcc: error: exclude.cpp: No such file or directory. 

In fact this file is located in the following directory:
 ./pygtftk/stats/intersect/read_bed/exclude.cpp

And setup.py indicates that it is located in that directory:
   cython_ologram_3 = Extension(name='pygtftk.stats.intersect.read_bed.read_bed_as_list',
                         sources=["pygtftk/stats/intersect/read_bed/read_bed_as_list.pyx",
                                  "pygtftk/stats/intersect/read_bed/exclude.cpp"],  # Include custom Cpp code
                         extra_compile_args=extra_comp_cython, extra_link_args=extra_link_cython,
                         include_dirs=[np.get_include()],
                         language='c++')

I have been searching but found no way to fix it.
Any idea would be greatly appreciated.
Best

Try removing the distutils: sources comment from the .pyx file

That's it. I dont't know what has changed for this to become an error... But, Thanks a lot !
